# How to I turn an Android device navigation bar color to white without the images still being white

Tags: android-layout, colors, navigation

[This is an image of the results I get when changing the navigation bar color using Window w = this.getWindow();w.setNavigationBarColor(Color.parseColor(0xFFFFFFFF));](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3g9D.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYpgg.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From version `1.5.0` of [Core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) library it is pretty simple to change navigation icons color to dark using this code in your activity:

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
```

But be aware that dark navigation icons are supported only from Android 8.0 (API level 26). On lower OS versions you should keep navigation bar color darker, to keep navigation icons visible.